# Where am I wrong about this bitwise expression?

Tags: bit-manipulation, bitwise-operators, bitwise-and

Game Maker Studio 2 has a downloadable demo of a dungeon top down game. In it there is a collision check script. The part of it for walking left is as follows:

```
x += -4;
var tx = (x-16)>>5; /* check right edge (my note: this gets the tile x-index
for the wall on the left, as each tile is 32 pixels wide. I think they 
copied the part for walking right and didn't fix the comment)*/
var ty1 = ((y+16)>>5);
var ty2 = ((y-16)>>5);

// collision data never has flips etc...
var tile1 = tilemap_get(WallMap, tx,ty1 )& tile_index_mask;
var tile2 = tilemap_get(WallMap, tx,ty2 )& tile_index_mask;
if(( tile1!=0 ) || (tile2!=0))
{ x = (x&~31)+16; }
```

(I replaced some variables and macros with their value. The +16 parts are for sprite adjustment. The sprite origin of the player (x,y) is set 16 pixels away from its edges).

The last line is what bothers me.

31 in bit is 00000000000000000000000000011111.

~31 in bit then is 11111111111111111111111111100000.

so x&~31 should really just set the last 5 digits of the x bit to 0.

But x=0,y=0 is the upper left part of the room. The smaller x is, the closer it is to the left side.

So what I gather from this is that when x collides with a wall on its left while walking left, this function sets its origin closer to the left, into the wall. Which doesn't make sense.

To my understanding, the last line should have been { x = (x&~31)+32+16; }, to snap the player origin to the left side of the wall tile, move it 32 pixels to the right side of the wall, then 16 pixels more to adjust to the sprite width.

Yet running the game, it works as intended. Trying to walk left into a wall keeps you in place. Where am I mistaken?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I don't think this issue is really about the bitwise aspect of it. The way I interpret this code, is that `x` represents the "origin" of the sprite and `x - 16` its left edge. Then `tx = (x-16)>>5` computes the x coordinate of the tile that *the left edge* is in, which is collision tested and so forth.

However, at that same moment, the origin of the sprite is still in the tile that you're standing on (the movement offset is smaller than half the sprite width, so the tentative movement does not move the origin into a different tile in one step), and that is the `x` which is used in `(x&~31)+16`. Therefore, `x&~31` rounds down to the left border of the tile you're standing on, not the left border of the wall tile.

Comment: > (the movement offset is smaller than half the sprite width, so the tentative movement does not move the origin into a different tile in one step) Genius. Thank you.

Comment: Though from their perspective I'd say it's pretty poor design. Tried to increase the speed to more than 16 and indeed the whole collision system broke down.